# Get User Details by Access Token From Admin

Tags: access, rest-api, token

I have two servers which are written in yii2 and magento respectively. The yii2 application has file module and magento has commerce and user module. the current problem is whenever user needs to upload the file to yii2, user only sends the access token. How do i retrieve user details (id) from the magento using only access token?

Thanks

Comment: specific customer user, but i want to retrieve the user details using the token not id. I want to retrieve it from the other servers using oauth

Answer (score 2):

First create token from **Admin->System->integrations** then use below code.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://your_domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria");
$token = 'your_token';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

**Hope this will help :)**