# Magento 2: Get Admin User Details By Token Rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to get admin user details by providing a token via HTTP header. How could I retrieve admin user details of this on Rest API.

Comment: Refer this answer :    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191770/get-user-details-by-access-token-from-admin

Comment: That answer is for get customer details. I want is to get admin detail by token.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but for future reference:

I assume you are talking about getting the admin user details during **an authenticated REST request with an integration admin token**. In that case you don't need to get the admin user ID from the token yourself because Magento does already associate the request with an admin ID in the authentication process. Thanks to that you can just use the `UserContext` class, to get the ID and the `UserFactory` class to get the user model and load it via ID.

```php
use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
use Magento\User\Model\UserFactory;
...

class YourClass {
    private UserContextInterface $userContext;
    private UserFactory $userFactory;
    ...
                    
    public function __construct(
           UserContextInterface $userContext, 
           UserFactory $userFactory
    )
    {
           $this->userContext = $userContext;
           $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
           ...                   
    } 
    public function getAdminUser()
    {
           $userId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
           $user = $this->userFactory->create()->load($userId);
           return $user;
    }
}
```

***Disclaimer:*** Yes, `->load($id)` is deprecated. However, at the time of writing this answer, it is still used in the Magento core since service contracts haven't been implemented for the admin user model so far. Corrections are welcome.

**If, however, this is not your context** and you're looking to get an admin user explicitly by a token string (from a custom header?), you can have a look at the  `Magento\Webapi\Model\Authorization\TokenUserContext` class and use or reproduce its `->processRequest()` method:

```php
protected function processRequest()
    {
        if ($this->isRequestProcessed) {
            return;
        }

        $authorizationHeaderValue = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');
        if (!$authorizationHeaderValue) {
            $this->isRequestProcessed = true;
            return;
        }

        $headerPieces = explode(" ", $authorizationHeaderValue);
        if (count($headerPieces) !== 2) {
            $this->isRequestProcessed = true;
            return;
        }

        $tokenType = strtolower($headerPieces[0]);
        if ($tokenType !== 'bearer') {
            $this->isRequestProcessed = true;
            return;
        }

        $bearerToken = $headerPieces[1];
        $token = $this->tokenFactory->create()->loadByToken($bearerToken);

        if (!$token->getId() || $token->getRevoked() || $this->isTokenExpired($token)) {
            $this->isRequestProcessed = true;

            return;
        }

        $this->setUserDataViaToken($token);
        $this->isRequestProcessed = true;
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

- Take $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
- Parse the token from that by stripping out the "Bearer " text
- Look up this token in the table oauth_token and you can get the
  customer ID, admin user ID or integration ID

Answer (score 1):

Approach from @btl-sw works.
Instead of using deprecated **\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::load** method, you can use resource model to load user data:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface
 */
private $userContext;

/**
 * @var \Magento\User\Api\Data\UserInterfaceFactory
 */
private $userFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User
 */
private $userResource;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext
 * @param \Magento\User\Api\Data\UserInterfaceFactory $userFactory
 * @param \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User $userResource
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext,
    \Magento\User\Api\Data\UserInterfaceFactory $userFactory,
    \Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User $userResource
) {
    $this->userContext = $userContext;
    $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    $this->userResource = $userResource;
}

// fetch user data
$userId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
if ($userId) {
    $user = $this->userFactory->create();
    $this->userResource->load($user, $userId);
}
// now $user variable stores data about admin user
```

Answer (score 0):

i know that it's not possible yet. You have to create a web services that allow you to use method loadByUsername of \Magento\User\Model\User